# Como pegar as cordenadas X e Y de um movieclip no ActionScript 3 ou JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, coordenadas

Olá, sou novo por aqui e tenho uma dúvida que esta me dando um baita trabalho.

Preciso capturar em uma variável as coordenadas X e Y de um determinado movieclip que está no meu palco (canvas no html5) mas não sei como fazer :(

**Estou usando AnimateCC 2018 com saida para HTML5**, é muito escasso qualquer tipo de artigo sobre desenvolvimento no animate, se alguém souber ficarei grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para você acessar um objeto criado no palco, como seu MovieClip por exemplo, você precisará utilizar `this` (assim como boa parte das funções globais) antes:

```
var movieclip = this.movieClipNoStage;
console.log(movieclip.x);
console.log(movieclip.y);
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
console.log(this.movieClipNoStage.x);
console.log(this.movieClipNoStage.y);
```

[Neste link](https://helpx.adobe.com/br/animate/kb/as-to-html5.html) estão as principais informações do que você precisa saber sobre a diferença entre a programação ActionScript 3.0 e o HTML5 Canvas no Animate CC. Ele ensina você a converter seu código.

Comment: Muito obrigado @bio problema resolvido! :D